# How to make a sentence inside a haml file bold?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

Here's the code in my haml file:

```
= render :partial => _paragraph,
         :locals => {:content =>  "It is hot. But something's definitely up."}
```

How can I make the last sentence bold?

Comment: Use a regex, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472655/regular-expression-in-haml-html-attribute

Comment: seems not relevant to my question.

Comment: It's a solution to make the last sentence bold but, if you found something better, good for you :) GL

Comment: Improve the title and edit the code example (less noise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the  tags in your string, then insert them as raw text in your paragraph partial

```
= render :partial => _paragraph, :locals => {:content =>  "It's one thing to notice an uptick in appetite if you've been training hard at the gym, or if you're pregnant or PMS-ing. <b>But when you always feel like a bottomless pit for no obvious reason, then something's definitely up.</b>"}
```

And in _paragraph

```
= raw content
```